# Using some code of libGDX in native OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

I'm trying to create 3D live wallpaper using native OpenGL ES 2.0. But it's too long without using any kind of framework. So I decided to use libGDX. I want to use some classes like `SpriteBatch`, `TextureRegion`, `OrthographicCamera` etc. How to initialize it from native OpenGL? I know about libGDX - live wallpaper plugin, but it's too slow to resume thread after pausing (about 1 second). Or perhaps, someone knows how to accelerate it.

Comment: Try using `AndEngine`  wallpaper extension :-https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Comment: I need to create 3D wallpaper. AFAIK AndEngine was designed for 2D app

Comment: Yes, but you did not mention it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can selectively use just the libGDX primitives without pulling in the rest of the libGDX framework.  The synchronization and globals used throughout the primitives depend on the initialization and setup of the rest of the framework.

I think it would be better to figure out what is slow after resume for the live wallpaper.  I don't think libGDX is doing much on that path.  (It will restore all the OpenGL context that was lost, but you would have to do that manually anyway.)

Comment: I have a lot of big images and every time when it restores it takes a lot of time! How to prevent it? Should I decrease size of images?

Comment: Yes, restoring big images/textures will take a while and is probably the source of your slowdown (a profiler will tell you more concretely).  This might help, too: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html